# Adding Plain text headers in API Blueprint

Tags: api, markdown, apiblueprint, apiary

API Blueprint appears to have an undocumented rule that prevents plain text headers below or between resource groups. I have three plain text headers above my resource group that display with no problems, but if I try to put a plain text header below it, I get the following “semantic issues” in Apiary:

```
unexpected header block, expected a group, resource or an definition, e.g. '# Group <name>', '# <resource name> [<URI>]' or '# <HTTP method> <URI>

dangling message-body asset, expected a pre-formatted code block, indent every of it's line by 12 spaces or 3 tabs
```

The [documentation](https://apiblueprint.org/documentation/examples/04-grouping-resources.html) states "Any following resource definition is considered to be a part of this group until another group is defined", but it doesn't address other types of headers.

Can this be overcome or do I need to keep all my plain text headers above my resource group?

Answer (score 1):

> do I need to keep all my plain text headers above my resource group?

**Yes**. And even there it might/should fail.

Once a Resource Group section is opened in API Blueprint, only the following can follow:

- `0+` **Resource Group** sections

  - `0+` **Resource** sections
- `0+` **Data Structures** section

The designed space for Markdown annotations in API Blueprint are indented blocks under a documented section header (resource, group, ...). This is called a [section description](https://apiblueprint.org/documentation/specification.html#description) in the documentation.

The full structure of an API Blueprint document conforms to [this](https://apiblueprint.org/documentation/specification.html#blueprint-document-structure) grammar.